# Как получить список пользователей с доступом к папке/файлу

Tags: python, файлы, безопасность

В ОС Windows в свойствах папок/файлов есть вкладка "Безопасность", в которой перечислен список групп и пользователей имеющих доступ.
Как с помощью Python можно получить эту информацию (Пользователь - Тип доступа)?

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
from winsys import fs
base = "C:/Program Files"
for f in fs.flat (base):
    print(f"\n{f.path}\n")
    for ace in f.security().dacl:
        flags_str = ", ".join (fs.FILE_ACCESS.names_from_value (ace.access))
        print(f"  {ace.trustee} => {flags_str}\n")
```